# UICollectionViewCells content repeats every 2 cells in Horizontal Scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that holds 10 items (images retrieved from Parse.com) Every cell covers the entire screen and it is set as a Horizontal Scroll.

Inside the cell I have a 'Like Button' that when clicked it changes color. The problem is that if I click the like button in cell 1 then cell 3, cell 5, and so on also changes the buttons color.. and if I click on cell 0 then cell 2, cell 4 and so on changes it color also.

I tried changing the UICollectionView cells size and made is so that the 10 cells fit in the screen. When I did that, no buttons repeated. The only change was in the button I clicked. Any thoughts as why this is happening and how can I fix it? I need the Cells to be the entire Screen.

My Code:

**VestimentaDetailViewController.m**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 10;

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
[cell.progressView setProgress:0.02];

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loadingLook.png"];

PFFile *storeLooks = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%ld", (long)indexPath.item]];

[storeLooks getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && data.length > 0) {

        cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    } else {

        cell.progressView.hidden = YES;

    }
} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    float percent = percentDone * 0.02;
    [cell.progressView setProgress:percent];
    if (percentDone == 100){
        cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
    }
}];

return cell;
}
```

**VestimentaDetailCell.m**

```
- (IBAction)likeLook:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];

    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        NSLog(@"Liked Image");

}
}
```

Comment: It would most likely have to do with the way you are populating them, and dequeue'ing them or not. You need to post your code that is relevant to this, if you would like help.

Comment: This is caused by cell reuse. If you don't understand that concept, then you need to do some reading of the docs.

Comment: @WilliamRiley I have added my code, please view. (The button is added on storyboard, inside the cell which has the action of likeLook inside the cell.m file)

Answer (score 0):

Collection and table views recycle their cells.  I think what's happening is that if you like cell 1 then cell 3, cell 5, so on... are all using a recycled cell 1.

To fix this, set the button color for **all** cells the are being dequeued into cellForRowAtItemPath to be the default button color.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get cell and stuff
    ...

    cell.likeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```